# Passing down data between widgets

Tags: flutter

I have a parent widget `_CalendarPageState` and two child widgets `nameColumnContainer2` and `nameColumn2`. I have a data under `int listLoc = list.indexOf(time);` inside `nameColumnContainer2` that I want to pass down to `nameColumn2`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'update_green_page.dart';

import '../data/repository_service_addcash.dart';
import '../models/addcash.dart';
import 'widget_ui/choice_chip.dart';

class CalendarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalendarPageState createState() => _CalendarPageState();
}

class _CalendarPageState extends State<CalendarPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: nameColumnContainer2(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> nameColumnContainer2() {
    var list = <DateTime>[];
    DateTime start = DateTime(2019, 12, 01);
    final end = DateTime(2021, 12, 31);

    while (start.isBefore(end)) {
      list.add(start);
      start = start.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }

    var listDates = list.map((DateTime time) {
      return DateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(time);
    }).toList();

    return list.map((DateTime time) {
      int listLoc = list.indexOf(time); //NEED TO PASS THIS DOWN TO nameColumn2
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue)),
        width: 120,
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<List<AddCash>>(
              future: future,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Column(
                    children:
                        snapshot.data.map((todo) => nameColumn2(todo)).toList(),
                  );
                } else {
                  return SizedBox();
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Widget nameColumn2(AddCash addCash) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 120.0,
      height: 60.0,
      color: Colors.green,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('${addCash.amount}'),
          listLoc % 6 == 0
              ? Text('${addCash.amount}')
              : listLoc % 2 == 0 ? Text('no') : Text('d')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I pass the data up to the parent widget so it's available in both widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the BlocProvider widget in your parent widget or directly in your main.dart.

Here is an exemple:

- First declare your BlocProvider

```
final MainBloc mainBloc = MainBloc();
return BlocProvider(
    bloc: mainBloc,
    child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/CalendarPage',
        onGenerateRoute: router.generator,
    ),
);
```

- BlocProvider content

```
class BlocProvider extends InheritedWidget {
    final MainBloc bloc;
    final Widget child;

    BlocProvider({Key key, @required this.child, @required this.bloc}) : super(key: key);

    static BlocProvider of(BuildContext context) {
        return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(BlocProvider);
    }

    @override
    bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

- Create a bloc (so you can separate your logic from your ui) and fill in the data you need

```
class MainBloc {
    //Declare the data you need in your tree
}
```

- And finally to recover your data in your parent/children

```
your_data = BlocProvider.of(context).bloc.your_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to pass `listLoc` down to `nameColumn2`